# Is there a good examples and documentation of jface databinding framework for Eclipse 3.4?

Tags: java, eclipse, data-binding, jface

The official site is quite scarce and most of the examples are EMF- related and for Eclipse 3.5 But what if one uses 3.4 target Eclipse platform and does not use EMF. 
I am specifically interested in Tree Viewer examples, but good example and documentation is always appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some good resources:

- [JFace databinding on eclipse wiki (incl. tutorial)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFace_Data_Binding)
- [The FAQ which links to some snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding_FAQ)
- [An example that shows databinding with a ListViewer](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataBinding/ar01s04.html)

I do not think, there's a major difference between JFace databinding in eclipse 3.4 and 3.5. The concepts are still the same (ISWTObservables, etc).

**Edit**

[Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html#jface) demonstrates an observable Listviewer with the following code:

```
// Define the viewer
viewer = new ListViewer(parent);
viewer.setContentProvider(new ObservableListContentProvider());
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
// Just for testing we create sample data
createExampleData(persons);
input = new WritableList(persons, Person.class);
// Set the writeableList as input for the viewer
viewer.setInput(input);
```

The introduction encourages that this works with TreeViewers aswell. The Content provider you need it `org.eclipse.jface.databinding.viewers.ObservableListTreeContentProvider`. It's a bit more complicated, because you need a list factory and a TreeStructureAdvisor to construct this content provider. That's all help I can provide. Didn't find an example either and didn't use databinding with tree viewers so far. So from now on the JFace API doc has to be your friend ;)

Comment: Yes, the links to the official eclipse site I have found myself of course. However, as I already mentioned, there is very little info there in general. Also there is no example for a TreeViewer in the snippets section. Plus, if you compare e.g. latest org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.3.1.M20090826-0800.jar and what comes with eclipse 3.4 org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.2.1.M20080827-0800a.jar you will find both quite different.

Comment: The third link is not from the eclipse wiki.

Comment: Yep, but it is for ListViewer. I was hoping that there is a ready example with trees out there. Perhaps if a Tree is considered as a collection of lists representing each node's children...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [comprehensive list](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.examples.databinding/src/org/eclipse/jface/examples/databinding/snippets/) of samples. [This one](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.examples.databinding/src/org/eclipse/jface/examples/databinding/snippets/Snippet019TreeViewerWithListFactory.java?revision=1.7&view=markup) is specifically related to TreeViewer.